I keep getting a 405 error on my Django Blog
I'm having an issue with my Django Blog. Every time I try to turn on the About Me Page, I get a 405 Error.
For context, here's my code:
posts/views.py:
from django.views.generic import View
from .models import Post



class AboutView(View):
    template_name = "aboutme.html"

posts/url.py:

from django.urls import re_path
from .views import AboutView
urlpatterns = [
re_path(r'post/aboutme/', AboutView.as_view())

]

templates/base.html:
<body>
 <div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                      </button>
                      <div class="py-2 bg-body-tertiary border-bottom">
                        <div class="py-2 bg-body-tertiary border-bottom">
                          <ul class="nav me-auto">
                                                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Homepage</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/posts">Blog</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/post/aboutme/">About Me</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
</ul>
 </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


For the sake of clarity, I've included the About Me page:
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} 
About Me 
{% endblock %}

{% block content %} 
<div class="center">
<p>
    Salutations!
    I'm TheBigL. A software Developer by trade.
</p> 
</div>

{% endblock %}

I always seem to get a 405 every time I open the About Me page. Is there any way I can fix this issue? Is my view configured correctly? Please let me know. Thanks in advance.
I search in Google. I've even tried to do method-based answers, but I wasn't satified with the result. I've even looked up folks who had similar issues, but it's nothing like what I have at the moment. It's relatively simple. Mine is a GET request, rather than a POST request.
EDIT: I forgot to change the import to this current state. It's something that I forgot.

You are not correctly importing Django's  View in from django.views.generic. It should be:
from django.views import View

See Using class-based views.

It still gave me the same error. I would like to note that I edited the import as a type on my end.

No you haven't corrected it. Look at the answer again... You're using from django.views.generic import View  but it should be from django.views import View

The View class is imported from django.views. If you need the generic views, then perhaps what you want for your aboutme page would be TemplateView. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/topics/class-based-views/#usage-in-your-urlconf

Template View worked. Thank you so much! Your solution did wonders.
